# What is the probability of a collision (birthday problem) using a Zipf distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assuming a random number generator gives one of *n* numbers using a [Zipf distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law) rather than a uniform distribution, what is the probability of each number being a number that was already generated previously?

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177692/birthday-paradox-for-non-uniform-distributions

Comment: Yes but that question is unanswered and less specific.